# How do you resolve an "Access Denied" error when invoking `image_uris.retrieve()` in AWS Sagemaker JumpStart?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-machine-learning

I am working in a SageMaker environment that is locked down. For example, my user account is prevented from creating S3 buckets. But, I can successfully run vanilla ML training jobs by passing in `role=get_execution_role` to an instance of the Estimator class when using an out-of-the-box algorithm such as XGBoost.

Now, I'm trying to use an algorithm (LightBGM) that is only available via the JumpStart feature in SageMaker, but I can't get it to work. When I try to retrieve an image URI via `image_uris.retrieve()`, it returns the following error:
`ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied`.

This makes some sense to me if my user permissions are being used when creating an object. But what I want to do is specify another role - like the one returned from get_execution_role - to perform these tasks.

Is that possible? Is there another work-around available? How can I see which role is being used?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving the error on `image_uris.retrieve()` ?
Can you provide a screenshot of where you are receiving the error exactly?

In the notebook you can confirm the role that is being used by running:
`! aws sts get-caller-identity`

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered this issue, it was a permissions issue with a bucket that had changed.
In the [SageMaker Python SDK source code](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk)  , there is a cache that is located at in an AWS-owned bucket: jumpstart-cache-prod-{region}. and a manifest.json that translates the ECR path for the image for you.
If you look at the stack trace, it could be erroring out at the code that is looking for the manifest.
One place to look is if there are new restrictions placed in IAM,  Included here is the [minimum policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/jumpstart-deploy.html) you need to access JumpStart (pretrained) models